# Google Oauth2 automatially renew token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm adding Oauth2 via Google to my Rails app using the `omniauth-google-oauth2` gem. I have everything set up according to the gem's readme. When I click the authorize button in my app, I am directed to Google to authorize the app. Once I'm sent back to my redirect path, I get a hash of data that includes the `token`, `refresh_token`, and `expires_at` (not `expires_in`), however `expires_at` is always equal to `Time.now.to_i`. The hash looks something like this:

```
=> auth.credentials
=> {
      token: 'token',
      refresh_token: 'refresh_token',
      expires_at: 1468603958
      expires: true
  }
```

What I would like to do is programmatically renew the user's token every time they log into the app, without forcing them to go through the initial authorization process. I have a similar token renewal flow set up for Facebook, but I can't figure out how to make this work for Google, since the token `expires_at` time is now.

My question is two-part:

1. Shouldn't the value of `expires_at` be in the future (e.g. 1 hour from now, or 30 days from now)?
2. How can I programmatically refresh the token using the `refresh_token` that I got when I first authorized the app? I can't seem to find a single example in Ruby on how to do this. I wanted to set up a method on my `GeneralController` in my app that checks the `expires_at` value of my `Identity` model and then runs some logic to renew the token, but I can't figure out how to renew the token. This also seems problematic given the `expires_at` value I got from Google is equal to `Time.now.to_i`. If I uses that value, it would trigger an infinite loop.

Here's what I want do do in pseudo code:

```
class GeneralController < ApplicationController
    before_action :renew_google_token, only: [:home]

    def renew_google_token
        # Get first Identity that will soon expire. This will be repeated unti lall identities are updated
        current_user.identities.where(provider: :google).where("expires_at < (?)", Time.now + 7.days).each do |identity|
            # Logic that pings Google and renews the token
            new_token_hash = something
            identity.update(token: new_token_hash.token, expires_at: Time.at(new_token_hash.expires_at))
        end
    end
end
```